# Why does the rate of turtle screen updates get slower as I update the turtle screen more?

Tags: python, animation

I made a test script to animate a box using `turtle.tracer(0)` and `turtle.update()` for animation frames. It updates constantly, but as the total amount of updates increases, the rate of each update on the screen gets slower and slower.
Here's my current code:

```
import turtle as t
t.title("Animation test")
t.tracer(0)
t.hideturtle()

def home():
    t.penup()
    t.goto(-250,250)
    t.color("black")
    t.fillcolor("white")
    t.pendown()
    t.begin_fill()
    for i in range(2):
        t.forward(500); t.right(90);
        t.forward(400); t.right(90);
    t.end_fill()
home()

class Square:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = -250
        self.y = 250
        self.xspeed = 5
        self.yspeed = 5
    def update(self):
        home()
        t.penup()
        t.goto(self.x,self.y)
        t.pendown()

        if self.x > 200 or self.x < -250:
            self.xspeed *= -1
        if self.y > 250 or self.y < -100:
            self.yspeed *= -1

        t.fillcolor("red")
        t.begin_fill()
        for i in range(4):
            t.forward(50)
            t.right(90)
        t.end_fill()

        self.x += self.xspeed
        self.y -= self.yspeed
        t.update()

s = Square()
for i in range(200):
    s.update()
```

This results in a fast animation at first, which soon slows down and then stops due to me only using 200 frames. I never changed the speed of the box, but the rate of `t.update()` having an affect on the screen is slower. Is there any way to prevent this? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you use to "clear" the screen only paints over it. That means the old drawings are still present under all those layers of old paint and slow the drawing down.

To clear all the drawings from the screen, you should use `t.clear()` in your `home()` function.

Comment: Thank you! That solved the problem entirely.